# How to read values from sessions

Tags: php, session, server-side

My web application sets session every time a user logs in.
I checked that sessions are properly set in http://mydomain.com/sessionfolder directory.
But I can't get those session values.

For example, in 'member_check.php' in root directory ('/'),

```
echo "Your name is = ".$_SESSION['membername'];
```

I get **'Your name is (blank)'**

Thanks.

Comment: How do you start your session?

Comment: Are you beginning each PHP file with `session_start()`?

Comment: did you set `$_SESSION['membername'] = "The NAME";`

Comment: Are you getting a blank for the name, or are you literally seeing the word "(blank)"? If it's the latter, then you are reading the session variable, and something is setting it to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the session savepath manualy? When I am using the servers supllied by my school I always have to set it by my self, because of some setting on the servers.

The following line should be included BEFORE the `session_start();`

`session_save_path('your_path_here');`

Don´t forget to create the folder and set the folder permissions to read and writeable for everyone..

Comment: Took me a while to figure out the first time too... =)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your script you must init sessions:

```
if ( ! session_id())
{
    session_start();
}
```